# ClientError: train channel is not specified with AWS object_detection_augmented_manifest_training using ground truth images

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, hyperparameters

I have completed a labelling job in AWS ground truth and started working on the notebook template for object detection.

I have 2 manifests which has 293 labeled images for birds in a train and validation set like this:

```
{"source-ref":"s3://XXXXXXX/Train/Blackbird_1.JPG","Bird-Label-Train":{"workerId":XXXXXXXX,"imageSource":{"s3Uri":"s3://XXXXXXX/Train/Blackbird_1.JPG"},"boxesInfo":{"annotatedResult":{"boundingBoxes":[{"width":1612,"top":841,"label":"Blackbird","left":1276,"height":757}],"inputImageProperties":{"width":3872,"height":2592}}}},"Bird-Label-Train-metadata":{"type":"groundtruth/custom","job-name":"bird-label-train","human-annotated":"yes","creation-date":"2019-01-16T17:28:23+0000"}}
```

Below are the parameters I am using for the notebook instance:

```
training_params = \
{
    "AlgorithmSpecification": {
        "TrainingImage": training_image, # NB. This is one of the named constants defined in the first cell.
        "TrainingInputMode": "Pipe"
    },
    "RoleArn": role,
    "OutputDataConfig": {
        "S3OutputPath": s3_output_path
    },
    "ResourceConfig": {
        "InstanceCount": 1,   
        "InstanceType": "ml.p3.2xlarge",
        "VolumeSizeInGB": 5
    },
    "TrainingJobName": job_name,
    "HyperParameters": { # NB. These hyperparameters are at the user's discretion and are beyond the scope of this demo.
         "base_network": "resnet-50",
         "use_pretrained_model": "1",
         "num_classes": "1",
         "mini_batch_size": "16",
         "epochs": "5",
         "learning_rate": "0.001",
         "lr_scheduler_step": "3,6",
         "lr_scheduler_factor": "0.1",
         "optimizer": "rmsprop",
         "momentum": "0.9",
         "weight_decay": "0.0005",
         "overlap_threshold": "0.5",
         "nms_threshold": "0.45",
         "image_shape": "300",
         "label_width": "350",
         "num_training_samples": str(num_training_samples)
    },
    "StoppingCondition": {
        "MaxRuntimeInSeconds": 86400
    },
 "InputDataConfig": [
    {
        "ChannelName": "train",
        "DataSource": {
            "S3DataSource": {
                "S3DataType": "AugmentedManifestFile", # NB. Augmented Manifest
                "S3Uri": s3_train_data_path,
                "S3DataDistributionType": "FullyReplicated",
                "AttributeNames": ["source-ref","Bird-Label-Train"] # NB. This must correspond to the JSON field names in your augmented manifest.
            }
        },
        "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
        "RecordWrapperType": "None",
        "CompressionType": "None"
    },
    {
        "ChannelName": "validation",
        "DataSource": {
            "S3DataSource": {
                "S3DataType": "AugmentedManifestFile", # NB. Augmented Manifest
                "S3Uri": s3_validation_data_path,
                "S3DataDistributionType": "FullyReplicated",
                "AttributeNames": ["source-ref","Bird-Label"] # NB. This must correspond to the JSON field names in your augmented manifest.
            }
        },
        "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
        "RecordWrapperType": "None",
        "CompressionType": "None"
    }
]
```

I would end up with this being printed after running my ml.p3.2xlarge instance:

```
InProgress Starting
InProgress Starting
InProgress Starting
InProgress Training
Failed Failed
```

Followed by this error message: 
**'ClientError: train channel is not specified.'**

Does anyone have any thoughts for how I can get this running with no errors? Any help is much apreciated!

**Successful run:** Below is the paramaters that were used, along with the Augmented Manifest JSON Objects for a successful run.

```
training_params = \
{
    "AlgorithmSpecification": {
        "TrainingImage": training_image, # NB. This is one of the named constants defined in the first cell.
        "TrainingInputMode": "Pipe"
    },
    "RoleArn": role,
    "OutputDataConfig": {
        "S3OutputPath": s3_output_path
    },
    "ResourceConfig": {
        "InstanceCount": 1,   
        "InstanceType": "ml.p3.2xlarge",
        "VolumeSizeInGB": 50
    },
    "TrainingJobName": job_name,
    "HyperParameters": { # NB. These hyperparameters are at the user's discretion and are beyond the scope of this demo.
         "base_network": "resnet-50",
         "use_pretrained_model": "1",
         "num_classes": "3",
         "mini_batch_size": "1",
         "epochs": "5",
         "learning_rate": "0.001",
         "lr_scheduler_step": "3,6",
         "lr_scheduler_factor": "0.1",
         "optimizer": "rmsprop",
         "momentum": "0.9",
         "weight_decay": "0.0005",
         "overlap_threshold": "0.5",
         "nms_threshold": "0.45",
         "image_shape": "300",
         "label_width": "350",
         "num_training_samples": str(num_training_samples)
    },
    "StoppingCondition": {
        "MaxRuntimeInSeconds": 86400
    },
    "InputDataConfig": [
        {
            "ChannelName": "train",
            "DataSource": {
                "S3DataSource": {
                    "S3DataType": "AugmentedManifestFile", # NB. Augmented Manifest
                    "S3Uri": s3_train_data_path,
                    "S3DataDistributionType": "FullyReplicated",
                    "AttributeNames": attribute_names # NB. This must correspond to the JSON field names in your **TRAIN** augmented manifest.
                }
            },
            "ContentType": "application/x-recordio",
            "RecordWrapperType": "RecordIO",
            "CompressionType": "None"
        },
        {
            "ChannelName": "validation",
            "DataSource": {
                "S3DataSource": {
                    "S3DataType": "AugmentedManifestFile", # NB. Augmented Manifest
                    "S3Uri": s3_validation_data_path,
                    "S3DataDistributionType": "FullyReplicated",
                    "AttributeNames": ["source-ref","ValidateBird"] # NB. This must correspond to the JSON field names in your **VALIDATION** augmented manifest.
                }
            },
            "ContentType": "application/x-recordio",
            "RecordWrapperType": "RecordIO",
            "CompressionType": "None"
        }
    ]
}
```

Training Augmented Manifest File generated during the running of the training job

```
Line 1
{"source-ref":"s3://XXXXX/Train/Blackbird_1.JPG","TrainBird":{"annotations":[{"class_id":0,"width":1613,"top":840,"height":766,"left":1293}],"image_size":[{"width":3872,"depth":3,"height":2592}]},"TrainBird-metadata":{"job-name":"labeling-job/trainbird","class-map":{"0":"Blackbird"},"human-annotated":"yes","objects":[{"confidence":0.09}],"creation-date":"2019-02-09T14:21:29.829003","type":"groundtruth/object-detection"}}


Line 2
{"source-ref":"s3://xxxxx/Train/Blackbird_2.JPG","TrainBird":{"annotations":[{"class_id":0,"width":897,"top":665,"height":1601,"left":1598}],"image_size":[{"width":3872,"depth":3,"height":2592}]},"TrainBird-metadata":{"job-name":"labeling-job/trainbird","class-map":{"0":"Blackbird"},"human-annotated":"yes","objects":[{"confidence":0.09}],"creation-date":"2019-02-09T14:22:34.502274","type":"groundtruth/object-detection"}}


Line 3
{"source-ref":"s3://XXXXX/Train/Blackbird_3.JPG","TrainBird":{"annotations":[{"class_id":0,"width":1040,"top":509,"height":1695,"left":1548}],"image_size":[{"width":3872,"depth":3,"height":2592}]},"TrainBird-metadata":{"job-name":"labeling-job/trainbird","class-map":{"0":"Blackbird"},"human-annotated":"yes","objects":[{"confidence":0.09}],"creation-date":"2019-02-09T14:20:26.660164","type":"groundtruth/object-detection"}}
```

I then unzip the model.tar file to get the following files:hyperparams.JSON, model_algo_1-0000.params and model_algo_1-symbol

hyperparams.JSON looks like this:

```
{"label_width": "350", "early_stopping_min_epochs": "10", "epochs": "5", "overlap_threshold": "0.5", "lr_scheduler_factor": "0.1", "_num_kv_servers": "auto", "weight_decay": "0.0005", "mini_batch_size": "1", "use_pretrained_model": "1", "freeze_layer_pattern": "", "lr_scheduler_step": "3,6", "early_stopping": "False", "early_stopping_patience": "5", "momentum": "0.9", "num_training_samples": "11", "optimizer": "rmsprop", "_tuning_objective_metric": "", "early_stopping_tolerance": "0.0", "learning_rate": "0.001", "kv_store": "device", "nms_threshold": "0.45", "num_classes": "1", "base_network": "resnet-50", "nms_topk": "400", "_kvstore": "device", "image_shape": "300"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you again for your help. All of which were valid in helping me get further. Having received a response on the AWS forum pages, I finally got it working.

I understood that my JSON was slightly different to the augmented manifest training guide. Having gone back to basics, I created another labelling job, but used the 'Bounding Box' type as opposed to the 'Custom - Bounding box template'. My output matched what was expected. This ran with no errors!

As my purpose was to have multiple labels, I was able to edit the files and mapping of my output manifests, which also worked!

i.e.

```
{"source-ref":"s3://xxxxx/Blackbird_15.JPG","ValidateBird":{"annotations":[{"class_id":0,"width":2023,"top":665,"height":1421,"left":1312}],"image_size":[{"width":3872,"depth":3,"height":2592}]},"ValidateBird-metadata":{"job-name":"labeling-job/validatebird","class-map":{"0":"Blackbird"},"human-annotated":"yes","objects":[{"confidence":0.09}],"creation-date":"2019-02-09T14:23:51.174131","type":"groundtruth/object-detection"}}
{"source-ref":"s3://xxxx/Pigeon_19.JPG","ValidateBird":{"annotations":[{"class_id":2,"width":784,"top":634,"height":1657,"left":1306}],"image_size":[{"width":3872,"depth":3,"height":2592}]},"ValidateBird-metadata":{"job-name":"labeling-job/validatebird","class-map":{"2":"Pigeon"},"human-annotated":"yes","objects":[{"confidence":0.09}],"creation-date":"2019-02-09T14:23:51.074809","type":"groundtruth/object-detection"}}
```

The original mapping was 0:'Bird' for all images through the labelling job.

Comment: Can you post the full CreateTrainingJob JSON that worked for you?  We are fighting through the same issue, and our AugmentedManifestFile format seems to match what you have posted here.  When changing to RecordIO format, we get a different 'ClientError: Got empty batch from pipe' error.  Looking to see what you did differently to get your job working.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have posted additional information. Hope this helps! If you need more, please let me know.

Comment: I was actually looking for the final version of the input JSON (not the manifest file).  In your original question, you posted this as: training_params = \
{
    "AlgorithmSpecification": {
        "TrainingImage": training_image, # NB. This is one of the named constants defined in the first cell.
        "TrainingInputMode": "Pipe"

Comment: Apologies! I have also uploaded more information on the output files from this training job.

Comment: I couldn't find this JSON file which is not a manifest file. Please could you be a bit more specific. The only files that were input were augmented manifest files (training and validation).

Comment: You would get this JSON by calling `aws sagemaker describe-training-job --training-job-name '<your-successful-job-name>'`, where <your-successful-job-name> is the name of a successful SageMaker training job.

Comment: I really do apologise, I am very new to aws, but happy to help if possible. Are you referring to the JSON I have posted in the original post? - what is unzipped from my model.tar file created from my successful training job. If not, do you know what the S3 bucket path would be for this file you are interested in?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, pipe mode with `AugmentedManifestFile` is not supported for the `image/jpeg` content type. To be able to use this feature, you will need to specify `RecordWrapperType` as `RecordIO` and `ContentType` as `application/x-recordio`.

Answer (score 1):

The 'AttributeNames' parameter need to be ['source-ref', 'your label here'] in both your train and validation channel

Comment: Hi Nilav, I have made some slight changes to the content above. I still receive the same result. Am I mislabeling the 'your label here' part? I have 7 different labels for birds and had used the name of the labelling job for that attribute (Which matches examples I have seen). My train and validation dataset also went through 2 different labelling jobs, hence the two different attributes between them.